# How to use React.useReducer (or equivalent) in class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-reducer

Is there any way to use `useReducer` or any equivalent thing in React native class Components?

Yeah reducer method is raw js function. Can we use it in class directly rather joining it with states of class?

```js
function init(initialCount) {
  return {count: initialCount};
}

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    case 'reset':
      return init(action.payload);
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return(...)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a wrapper component that uses the `useReducer` hook and pass the `state` and `dispatch` function as props.

Example:

```
const Wrapper = props => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialCount, init);

  return <App {...props} {...{ state, dispatch }} />;
};
```

This might be better abstracted into a reusable Higher Order Component though.

Example:

```
const withUseReducer = (...useReducerArgs) => Component => props => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(...useReducerArgs);

  return <Component {...props} {...{ state, dispatch }} />;
};
```

...

```
export default withUseReducer(reducer, initialCount, init)(App);
```

Consuming in class component:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  ...

  render() {
    const { state, dispatch } = this.props;

    ...

    return(...)
  }
}
```